# Removal of 3 or more consecutive letters in a string given by the user

Tags: python, variable-assignment

Candy Crush horizontal. The program asks for a string and outputs the string remaining after removing  groups of 3 or more consecutive identical characters. The removal of the groups continues until no more groups are found to be removed. The program should allow repetition until the user does not want to continue.

```
#Message
print("Hello! Welcome to Candy Crush!")
while True:
    decision = str(input("Would you like to add a string? "))
    if decision == "Yes" or decision == "yes":
        num = str(input("Please enter a string: "))
        list = list(num)
        print("Your original list is", list)
        print("Your original string: ", num)
        while len(list) >= 3:
            for i in range(len(list) - 2):
                if list[i] == list[i + 1] == list[i + 2]:
                    list.pop(i + 2)
                    list.pop(i + 1)
                    list.pop(i)
                    print("Your trimmed list is", list)
            result = "".join(list)
            print("\nThe output of your string is: ", result)
    if decision == "No" or decision == "no":
        print("Thank you for playing! Have a great day!")
        exit()
Traceback (most recent call last):
 Python Candy Crush.py", line 12, in <module>
    if list[i] == list[i + 1] == list[i + 2]:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Try adding a `break` after you've popped the items off the list, to break out of the for loop. I'd also suggest renaming the variable `list` to something like `my_list`, to avoid clashing with python's `list`. The program as written will loop forever in some cases, but hopefully this can be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Dark_Knight and welcome to Stack Overflow!

Here is the solution I had in mind. Although this solves the problem, I wanted to make this a learning experience for you and other programmers who stumble upon this. I blocked off, with comments, the start and end of my changes as well as step by step comments on the decisions I made for the solution.

```
#Message
print("Hello! Welcome to Candy Crush!")
while True:
    decision = str(input("Would you like to add a string? "))
    if decision == "Yes" or decision == "yes":
        # Start of solution changes
        # Lets make variables more clear
        stringInput = str(input("Please enter a string: "))
        charactersInput = list(stringInput)
        print("Your original list is", charactersInput) # Still the same...
        print("Your original string: ", stringInput) # Also still the same
        # For our loop, idx will be used to track the index of the list
        idx = 0
        # Lets use a while loop instead of a for loop
        # We will exit the loop when there aren't 3 consecutive characters
        while idx < len(charactersInput) - 2:
            # Check if the current character is the same as the next 2
            if charactersInput[idx] == charactersInput[idx + 1] == charactersInput[idx + 2]:
                # If so, remove the current and next 2 characters
                # We are using pop() to remove the characters
                # So the next character will be at the current index
                charactersInput.pop(idx)
                charactersInput.pop(idx)
                charactersInput.pop(idx)
                # Okay, we made a change to the list, so we need to reset idx
                # As there might be a new set of 3 consecutive characters
                idx = 0
            else:
                # If the current character is not the same as the next two,
                # then increment idx by 1
                idx += 1
        result = "".join(charactersInput)
        # End of solution changes
        print("\nThe output of your string is: ", result)
    if decision == "No" or decision == "no":
        print("Thank you for playing! Have a great day!")
        exit()
```

Here are some things to keep in mind that might make finding your own solution easier.

- Make sure that all of your variables are clear and don't utilize keywords used in Python (or any other programming language). Using `list` for a list isn't descriptive and is the same terminology Python uses to work with lists
- Break down the problems into smaller pieces. While I was working I first asked "What type of loop do I need?", then "At my current iteration in the loop, what do I need to check?", etc, etc,
- Help out the community and include as many fixes you tried before creating a post. It not only helps people trying to help you out but also helps other users learn what solutions **don't** work

Comment: Some tips on StackOverflow to remember too: If you make any other changes to the code feel free to edit your post so other users know how to fix the solution if they stumbled upon it. And of course if this fixed it make sure to make this as the solution too! Just remember someone might need this a week/month/year (or more) from now and might find a well documented solution helpful.